# PROXIMITY_SCREEN_OFF_WAKE_LOCK is causing audio playback issues

Tags: android

I am developing a VOIP app and I use the PROXIMITY_SCREEN_OFF_WAKE_LOCK wake lock as illustrated below.

I have noticed that on many devices, when the proximity sensor is on and the screen goes black, then the audio playback of my app stops. This happens on HTC, LG, and Huawei devices.

Is there something additional that has to be done to prevent audio playback to be stopped when the sensor is triggered?  I have noticed the same issue on other VOIP app such as Skype.

```
int PROXIMITY_SCREEN_OFF_WAKE_LOCK = 32;    
mProximityWakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PROXIMITY_SCREEN_OFF_WAKE_LOCK, "myLock");
if(!mProximityWakeLock.isHeld()){
    mProximityWakeLock.acquire();
}
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 8):

We were having the same problem. What we really detected was that the input socket stopped receiving data when the screen was off with the WakeLock, so we were sending zeros to the AudioTrack.

In order to improve that, we quit using PROXIMITY_SCREEN_OFF_WAKE_LOCK and now are using SensorManager (we had a look into the Linphone code):

```
public class InCallActivity extends Activity implements SensorEventListener {

    private SensorManager mSensorManager;
    private Sensor mProximity;

    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
    }

    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        final Window window = getWindow();
        WindowManager.LayoutParams lAttrs = getWindow().getAttributes();
        View view = ((ViewGroup) window.getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content)).getChildAt(0);
        if (event.values[0] > 4) {
            // turn on screen
            Log.v("LlamadaActivity", "Encendemos pantalla");
            lAttrs.flags &= (~WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
            view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        else {
            // turn off screen
            Log.v("LlamadaActivity", "Apagamos pantalla");
            lAttrs.flags |= WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
            view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
        window.setAttributes(lAttrs);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mSensorManager = (SensorManager)getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
        mProximity = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_PROXIMITY);
        mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mProximity, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);

        // Para que la pantalla no se apague, y que la encienda aunque este apagada y bloqueada
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
        //
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: This works like a charm, I used event.value[0]>=3, because the max value of the sensor was 4, so the screen is always off. Don't know if this solves the OP question, but is what I'm looking for.

Comment: It works and is a good alternative for avoiding wakelock problems but for me the screen turns white (Nexus 6, API N preview 4), could be related to the theme but just giving a heads up to others trying it

Comment: Apparently this doesn't work on newer Samsung phones https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55488799/proximity-screen-off-wake-lock-not-working-with-samsung?rq=3

Comment: Here's another one related to Samsung phones https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61498407/listening-to-proximity-screen-off-wake-lock