# How to test proximity sensor in Samsung galaxy S10 or S10+?

Tags: java, android

I want to test proximity sensor on Samsung newer model (s10 or s10+), I have used the old conventional way to register the listener for the proximity sensor and it is working for all the device except these 2 ones. I have searched over the internet and come to know that S10 has proximity sensor under the display (a blinking pixel lights up during call etc). I have also used many 3rd party sensor testing apps but none of them is working for S10. Does anyone know what Samsung has changed? how we can access S10 proximity sensor programmatically?
I have tried the below code but it is always toasting far.

```
@Override
   public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
       if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_PROXIMITY) {
           if (event.values[0] >= -SENSOR_SENSITIVITY && event.values[0] <= SENSOR_SENSITIVITY) {
               //near
               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "near", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           } else {
               //far
               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "far", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           }
       }
   }

   @Override
   public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "accuracy changed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }
```

Comment: apparently the proximity sensor seems to be somewhat broken on a lot of s10/s10+ devices oO

Comment: Yeah i guess so,Because when i run the above code is just gives a constant value 5.0 and then it stops don't know why. As i checked sensor listener wasn't register but don't know why it stops after giving 1 value, why sensorChanged callback doesn't give response repeatedly

Comment: I got the same thing. onSensorChanged gets called once right after register but never again

Comment: if anyone get the solution please post here also

Comment: I guess that it might be using some custom sensor. Try checking CPU Z if they can do that should be able to do soo

Answer (score 3):

You can use secret code *#77692#
[Test proximity sensor on Samsung Galaxy S10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/onAiM.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

Try not to use the sensor API directly. To test the proximity sensor just acquire a wake lock created with PROXIMITY_SCREEN_OFF_WAKE_LOCK parameter.

It will not help to get the measured distance, but the screen will start to turn off/on when you put your palm over the sensor.

```
class ProximityMgr(context: Context) {
    private val powerManager: PowerManager = context.getSystemService()!!
    private val wakeLock: PowerManager.WakeLock

    init {
        wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(
                PowerManager.PROXIMITY_SCREEN_OFF_WAKE_LOCK, 
                "lock:proximity_screen_off")
    }

    fun acquire() {
        if (powerManager.isWakeLockLevelSupported(PowerManager.PROXIMITY_SCREEN_OFF_WAKE_LOCK)) {
            if (wakeLock.isHeld) {
                wakeLock.release()
            }
            wakeLock.acquire(WAKE_LOCK_TIMEOUT_MS)
        } else {
            Log.w(TAG, "not supported")
        }
    }

    fun release() {
        if (wakeLock.isHeld)
            wakeLock.release()
    }

    companion object {
        private const val TAG = "ProximitySensor"
        private const val WAKE_LOCK_TIMEOUT_MS: Long = 2 * 3600 * 1000
    }
}
```

This snippet was taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58950934/4466771).

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to turn on and test the proximity sensor.

Dial *#77692#  you wil get two sensors to test:

1: light sensor
2: Proximity sensor

You can't turn it on and keep it on. We just can test it by turning it on afterward it goes to off modus. Very strange from Samsung.

Maybe the next update will give the possibility to keep it on. So the screen won't go unlocked in the pocket.
 Hope this can help you.

Answer (score 0):

In simple terms(non-programatically)
Method1
star hash zero star hash(*#0*#)on dialer
A block of options will be there(red,green,blue,vibration,camera)in that select proximity sensor.now it will show the lux(luminious intensity)amount more light more lux.check that wise also.also u can hover now the display appears green with a vibration.
Method2
Do a call.During the call the right top area (left side of camera)a white dot will be blinking in the display itself.(looks like a pixel dot).now hover and check.