# Listening to PROXIMITY_SCREEN_OFF_WAKE_LOCK

Tags: android, wakelock, proximity, android-wake-lock, proximitysensor

I'm developing an app that lets the user store and listen to voice messages and I want to change the audio output source when the user brings the phone up to his ear.

I tried working with the `SensorManager` but I found out that Samsung devices have problematic proximity sensors (I have a Galaxy S10e). After a bit of research I found that the best option is using the `PROXIMITY_SCREEN_OFF_WAKE_LOCK` and now the screen turns off and on when I bring the phone to and from my ear (which is a good thing). However, using the wake lock doesn't call `onResume()` or `onPause()` nor does it send `ACTION_SCREEN_ON` or `ACTION_SCREEN_OFF` broadcasts.

Is there anyway to listen to the `PROXIMITY_SCREEN_OFF_WAKE_LOCK` activity so I could know when to change the audio output source?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone stumbles upon this post.
My solution was registering a `SenseorEventListener` **and** acquiring a `PROXIMITY_SCREEN_OFF_WAKE_LOCK` wake lock.

Apparently if a wake lock is acquired the proximity sensor works fine :)